# Ionic Build iOS - Fail

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I've been workign on this project for months now with no major issues. Today I can't even get it to build out. I ran "$ionic resources" and now I can't get my build to work at all.

I'm getting this error:

```
    ** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/Stopper.app Stopper/Images.xcassets
(1 failure)
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/colemanjeff/GitHub/StopperRC1/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,Stopper.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,Stopper,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/colemanjeff/GitHub/StopperRC1/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/colemanjeff/GitHub/StopperRC1/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/colemanjeff/GitHub/StopperRC1/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,Stopper.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,Stopper,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/colemanjeff/GitHub/StopperRC1/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/colemanjeff/GitHub/StopperRC1/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I'm not sure what caused the problem or how to fix it. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: could you try removing iOS platform and add it again and build

Comment: I tried $ionic platform rm ios
then $ionic platform add ios
then $ionic build ios

Keep getting Error code 65

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I actually did need to uninstall the platform, remove the plugin json file, and then reinstall everything.

Comment: that's what I meant in my previous comment.hope it resolved ur issue.

Comment: All good. I got it working now and uploaded to Apple. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Run (this will remove the old ionic ios platform)

```
sudo ionic platform rm ios
```

Then (this will install a new platform with privileges)

```
sudo ionic platform add ios
```

Then build your code ios/android

```
ionic build ios
ionic build android
```

This fixed it for me!

Might be that you should also run

```
sudo ionic resources
```

to generate new icon and splash screens.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, re-installation of Platform and Plugins once again resolves the issue.